# Potential at the center of a concentric sphere and shell

Tags: electrostatics, potential

If the electric potential of the inner metal sphere is $10$ V & that of the outer shell is $5$ V, then the potential at the centre will be :

[image]

The potential at the centre should be $10 + 5 = 15$ V as potential is constant inside a conducting sphere and a shell and because it is a scalar quantity it should be added. But the potential is actually $10$ V. Why does that happen ? Why does the outer shell have no effect on the potential ?

Comment: If the inner sphere is metallic, why do you think there must be a potential difference between it's surface and it's centre? You're given potential of the inner sphere is already $10~\rm V$, right?

Comment: there are 2 conditions if you charge the outer shell, or there is no net charge across the surface of outer shell, which one is given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $10~\rm V$ because the potential on the inner sphere is due to charge on both inner and outer sphere. That is when they said the inner sphere is at $10~\rm V$, it means that the total potential on the inner sphere is $10~\rm V$.

Individually, if both spheres were seperately kept, then each would have potential of $5~\rm V$ on them, so that at the centre, potential becomes $10~\rm V$.

Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the inner nor the outer shells have any effect on the *electric field* at the centre of the of the inner shell.

This is because of Gauss' theorem:

$$  \oint_S \mathbf{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}^2\mathbf{r} = \frac{Q_{\mathrm{in}\,S}}{\epsilon_0},$$
where $S$ is a sphere of radius $r<a$ and $Q$ is the charged enclosed by this surface $S$.

Since $r<a$, there is not charge enclosed and the electric field is zero: $\mathbf{E}|_{r=0}=0$.

Because the potential $V$ is related to the electric field as:
$$ \mathbf{E} = -\nabla V ,$$
you can actually, technically, have *any* value of the potential you want. Provided it's a constant. Because any constant is cancelled by the derivative $\nabla$. However, such a constant should agree with the boundary condition that at $r=a$ you have $10$ V.

So the potential at the centre should be $10$ V.